# Stack Overflow claims I don't need to register, but I do

Tags: support, registration

This is what I figured out:

> Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It's 100% free, no registration required.

But the truth is you **need to register** before you can ask a question; you are only allowed to answer questions as a guest. Is this true? 100% was advertisment ?

Comment: I can agree that the "no registration required" part can be slightly misleading, but the "100% free" part does not at all mean that you can use 100% of the site without registering. It means you don't need to ever pay anything to use any part of the site, which is 100% true.

Comment: Not worth the confusion; the message now ends with, "It's 100% free."

Answer (score 8):

I think it means **no registration required to see/browse the questions and answers**.

Comment: but it wrote 100% what thats mean

Comment: @Jackcob `100% free` means you cost no fee to use it.

Comment: @Jackcob This is in contrast to experts-exchange and quarta, where you need to sign up or pay to see the content on their sites.

Comment: @gunr2171 You don't actually have to pay to see content on experts-exchange.  You just have to scroll and scroll and scroll further down than anyone would think to scroll.

Comment: I dislike Quora for this exact reason - you have to register to see the answers.

Answer (score 7):

Most our sites don't require registration to ask questions. A few do, including Stack Overflow, and we probably should vary up the wording there based on that.

However, note that the site is still 100% free to use (registering doesn't actually cost you any money), and you do not need to register to post answers.